# what regular expression can extract data I need?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
url = '//item.taobao.com/item.htm?id\u003d528341191030\u0026ns\u003d1\u0026abbucket\u003d0#detail'
```

I like to extract the number `528341191030` between the first two `\u`. I tried this,

```
m = re.search('\?id\u\d+d(\d+?)\u', url)
if m:
  print m.group(1)
```

But it doesn't work. What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: Can you tell us what the output was, whether that was an error or the incorrect output

Comment: Since search returns None, so it won't output anything. There isn't any error.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you need regex?
Here is a solution using [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
url.split("\u")[1].split("d")[-1]
'528341191030'
```

In terms of what is wrong with your regex, "\" is a special character, so you should use "\\" for backslash (so " \\\u" instead of "\u"):

```
m = re.search('\?id\\\u\d+d(\d+?)\\\u', url)
if m:
  print m.group(1)
```

Gives: 528341191030

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re):

> Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate
>   special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
>   invoking their special meaning. This collides with Python’s usage of
>   the same character for the same purpose in string literals; for
>   example, to match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\'
>   as the pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and
>   each backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string
>   literal.

Or,use **[Raw String Notation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation)**

```
m = re.search(r"\?id\\u\d+d(\d+?)\\u", url)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

Comment: @yi xiao: Thanks for the edit on raw string notation :)

Comment: Actually I tried to escape '\'  like this, 
url = '//item.taobao.com/item.htm?id\u003d528341191030\u0026ns\u003d1\u0026abbucket\u003d0#detail'
m = re.search('\?id\\u\d+d(\d+?)\\u', url)
      if m:
         print m.group(1)
 but it still doesn't work

Comment: You should add 3 "\" before "u". Please try copy-pasting the code sample and let me know

Comment: Yes! But why should I add 3 '\' before 'u'? Thanks.

Comment: In general I would suggest raw string notation. Without r'', if you try this: re.match("\\\u", "\u") you see that 3 "\" is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always try this (not super elegant but works):

```
first = url.find('\u') + 2
prev = 'u'
m = ""
for i in range(first, len(url)):
    if prev == '\' and url[i] == 'u':
         break
    else:
        m += url[i]
    if url[i] == 'd':
        m = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to parseurl and get the query string values

```
url = '//item.taobao.com/item.htm?id\u003d528341191030\u0026ns\u003d1\u0026abbucket\u003d0#detail'
import urllib.parse as urlparse
print ( urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query) )
print ( urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)['id'] )
```

Output:

```
{'id': ['528341191030'], 'ns': ['1'], 'abbucket': ['0']}
['528341191030']
```